# Manual mock with jest isn't working for imported constants

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've spent hours trying to mock a constant using a manual mock but it wouldn't work. Please help!!

Suppose that I want to test the `status` method shown here in `src/age.ts` by mocking the `CURRENT_AGE` variable.

```
// src/age.ts

import { CURRENT_AGE } from "./constants"

export class Age {

  /** 
   * return "OLD" if the CURRENT_AGE is over 50.
   * return "YOUNG" if otherwise.
   */
  public status() {
    if (CURRENT_AGE > 50) {
      return "OLD";
    } else {
      return "YOUNG";
    }
  }

}
```

And `CURRENT_AGE` is defined in the same directory

`src/constants.ts`

```
export const CURRENT_AGE=45;
```

In my test, I create a manual mock to replace the `CURRENT_AGE` variable as follows:

`src/__mocks__/constants.ts`

```
export const CURRENT_AGE = 100;
```

But when I run the test file below, `CURRENT_AGE` still has the value in the original module and not the one in the mock.

Test in `__tests__/src/age.test.ts`:

```
import {Age} from "../../src/age";

describe("Test Age", () => {
  let mockConstants;
  let age;

  beforeAll(() => {
    mockConstants = jest.mock("../../src/constants");
    age = new Age();
  });

  it("Test status module", () => {

    expect(age.status()).toBe("OLD"); // But I get "YOUNG" instead.

    // I even tried importing and printing the CURRENT_AGE here. I
    // still get the original 45 instead of the mock 100 :((
  });
  
  afterAll(() => {
    mockConstants.mockRestore();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **mocking is used to mock the 3rd party implementations or API integrations**.

If we consider your case, the constants you are mocking here, you are just mocking it, **the class will always use constants from your constants.ts file as it is imported into the age class file** and the class implement functionality wouldn't lose at any time it stays same always.

If you want to make changes in your constants for testing, you should think about the different logic.

Comment: Do you have an alternative that I can use to mock the constant?

Comment: I don't think, You can just make changes to the main constants file to test.